# Mysql returns different results for monthwise data of an year and whole year's data

Tags: mysql

Here is my following SQL query:

```
SELECT count(`pd`.`email`)
FROM `social_user_login_details` AS `pd`
WHERE (DATE( db_add_date ) BETWEEN 'START-DATE' AND 'END-DATE')
GROUP BY `email`
```

If I put starting date and ending date of each month of year and get its count and calculates its total on calculator, it is 6357. But if I put starting date as 1st Jan and ending date as 31st Dec, then it shows 6325. Why this is different result for different dates?

Table Structure:

```
id          bigint(20)
uid         varchar(255)
user_name   varchar(150)
password    varchar(250)
email       varchar(150)
firstname   varchar(150)
lastname    varchar(150)
db_add_date date
```

Comment: If you can find the smallest dataset that illustrates the problem, that would be helpful.

Comment: There are almost million records in table.

Comment: It's a little odd to GROUP BY the thing you're counting.

Comment: What happens if you group by `month(db_add_date)` instead of eamil and add a `WITH ROLLUP` after the group by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Strawberry hit the nail on the head -- when you group by email, each unique email will be counted once. If an email occurs in more than one month, it will be counted in the date range where it occurs. When you count the year as a whole, the grouped emails will only be counted once.

You can try the following, which will display the sums for the months and the total simultaneously:

```
SELECT count(*), month(db_add_date)
FROM `social_user_login_details` AS `pd`
WHERE (DATE( db_add_date ) BETWEEN 'START-DATE' AND 'END-DATE')
GROUP BY `email`, month(db_add_date) WITH ROLLUP
```

I *think* that this will show the sum of all of the months, but I haven't had a chance to try it to see.

I can't think of a way of de-duplicating across months -- showing the first occurrence of an email address across months ... just sounds hairy, and ... to a certain extent, wrong -- this is one of those cases, like measuring the coastline of England with a yard-stick vs. a 12 inch ruler, where you're going to get different results depending on the unit you're measuring with.

Comment: This is the answer. Your query counts how many unique email addresses were used in a given period. To compare the sum of months will never give you the year result for this query, as a user might have logged in different months.

Comment: Thanks. I've checked it. Same thing happen in my db table. Thanks once again. Please give me solution to overcome this problem if possible.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should put year in start and end date in between query

```
WHERE pd.db_add_date BETWEEN #01/01/2016# AND #31/12/2016#;
```

or you can try this

```
WHERE month(pd.db_add_date) between '01' and '12'
```

Comment: Sample dates are used as follows:

For monthly Calculation:
from : 2016-01-01 to : 2016-01-31
from : 2016-02-01 to : 2016-02-29
from : 2016-03-01 to : 2016-03-31
.
.
from : 2016-12-01 to : 2016-12-31

For yearly data:

from : 2016-01-01 to : 2016-12-31